# Background color around child elements

Tags: html, css

I have 2 child anchor tags inside a parent div. I want to add a background color and some styles to the child divs without affecting the entire row.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class= 'about-header-container header-info' id='about-header' style='display: block;'>
    <a class='bio-header tablink' href='#bio-dashfolio'>Bio</a>
    <a class='timeline-header tablink' href='#timeline-dashfolio'>Timeline</a>
 </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.tablink {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-info {
margin-left: 80px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: red; /* trial color*/
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kesh92/t5zzk6oc/ 
Currently, the red affects the entire row from the `bio-header` child div. If I add a `width` property to the `.header-info` parent div, then there's no precise way to wrap it exactly around the children, especially given the red `background-color` for the children divs wraps itself perfectly around the first child div (being `bio-header`). Please help me add the red color around the children divs with equal left and right margins. 
Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is the result I want to achieve - 
[image]

Comment: Please provide *complete* minimal code, Your question, and fiddle have zero "child divs" so.... style the anchors...

Comment: change your display: block; to inline-block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```css
.header-info
{
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
 
}
.header-info a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-info">
    <a class="anchor"  href='#bio-dashfolio'>Bio</a>
    <a class="anchor" href='#timeline-dashfolio'>Timeline</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please see updated question for the result I wish to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but as soon as I add some space between the Bio and Timeline words, the result isn't achieved. Bio and Timeline are seperate words, not one.

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan i have added extra padding

Comment: Thanks a million @Parth Patel, this works perfectly! :D I see that I had used the `font-size` incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.tablink {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}

a {
  float: left;
}

.header-info {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/63nqdswL/

Comment: Thanks @ovokuru, but I want it to be a row around the child divs, not on it's individual elements. For example, in your solution, there's still space between the red around the individual anchor tags. Let me know if this makes sense, or you need more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` on parent, and `display:table-cell` on each child. `display:table-*` wraps tight so use `padding` on each child for spacing as needed.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.header-info {
  display: table;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  /* trial color*/
}
.tablink {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.bio-header {
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 5px;
}
.timeline-header {
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='about-header-container header-info' id='about-header'>
  <a class='bio-header tablink' href='#bio-dashfolio'>Bio</a>
  <a class='timeline-header tablink' href='#timeline-dashfolio'>Timeline</a>
</div>
```